# Why did Wesley Gibson's father take this action?

Tags: plot-explanation, wanted

Why was Wesley Gibson's (James McAvoy) father trying to shoot him? His father explains that he was trying to free him from the fraternity. But how was shooting him help free him from the fraternity? You can say all the other times he was trying to shoot others from the fraternity But in the scene where Wesley accidentally shoots the German guy his father shoots him? Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true, he shot him but he wasn't trying to kill him.

He deliberately shot him in the arm (which everyone knows that it is a safe place to shoot somebody without killing him) with a traceable bullet (Wesley's father always killed his targets with untraceable bullets) so as to lure him to the train so he could get Wesley away from them and tell him the truth.

Answer (score 2):

> Why was Wesley Gibson's (James McAvoy) father trying to shoot him?

## He wasn't.

If you refer back you see that every time Wesley's father shoots even remotely close to being *at* Wesley it's in response to being shot at *by* Wesley.

...And, in every case, Wesley's father's bullet stops Wesley' bullet... it happens three times....**that's not a coincidence**.

[image]

Comment: I am referring to the particular scene where wesley accidentally shoots the german guy (healer or the one who shows him the rat bomb). Here his father intentionally shoots him in his left arm. Why does he do that?

Comment: I'll watch it again but I don't recall Wesley being shot in that scene.

Comment: Either way...shooting someone in the arm in *self-defence* isn't the same as trying to kill someone.,,and we know that these guys hit what they're aiming at.